# How to Delete QuickBlox User tags from Application?

Tags: tags, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have searched through all the QBUser tutorials, but cannot find the way to delete the user tags.
Anyone knows how to do it from the application and without deleting the user and recreating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'Edit user' API

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Update_own_profile

```
QBUser user = new QBUser(); 
user.setId(53779);    
StringifyArrayList<String> tags = new StringifyArrayList();  
tags.add("man"); 
user.setTags(tags);   

QBUsers.updateUser(user, new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QBUser user, Bundle args) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(QBResponseException errors) {

    } 
});
```

Comment: I tried to update using empty tags, it did not work.
Changing the tags worked! Thank you!